kernel of $K[X,Y] \rightarrow K[\theta_1, \theta_2]$
Given a field $K$, for example the field of rational numbers ${\bf Q}$, and two algebraic numbers $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$ over $K$, what is the kernel of the morphism $$K[X,Y] \rightarrow K[\theta_1, \theta_2]$$ that sends $X$ to $\theta_1$ and $Y$ to $\theta_2$?
It contains $P_{\theta_1}(X)K[X,Y] + P_{\theta_2}(Y)K[X,Y]$, where$ P_{\theta_i}$ is the minimal polynomial of $\theta_i$ but I fail to see when it is equal. Maybe when $K[\theta_1] \cap K[\theta_2] = K$? If $\theta_1 = \theta_2$, I can show that the kernel is generated by $P_{\theta_1}(X)$ and $X-Y$. So there must be other generators in general.

Is this not the field extension by $\theta_1,\theta_2$?

@Chris $K[\theta_1, \theta_2]$ is the field extension by $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$.

Let $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ be algebraic over over $K$, and suppose that $\theta_1,\theta_2\notin K$, as other wise $K(\theta_1,\theta_2)=K$, and your ideal is given by $(x-\theta_1,y-\theta_2)$.
Let's see if we can't first write $K(\theta_1)[y]$ in terms of a quotient of $K[x,y]$. Let $a_i\theta^i_1\in K(\theta_1)$ (Einstein summation notation assumed) with $a_i\in K$, there is a canonical isomorphism:
$$K(\theta_1)[y]\cong K(\theta_1)\otimes_KK[y]$$
Which takes the element $y^ka_i\theta^i_1$ to the element $\theta^i_1\otimes y^ka_i$. We can identify $K(\theta_1)$ with $K[x]/(p_\theta)$, where $\theta_1^i$ gets mapped to the equivalence class $[x^i]$. Thus we have the following the isomorphism:
$$K(\theta_1)[y]\cong K[x]/(p_1)\otimes_kK[y]$$
where the element $y^ka_i\theta_1^i$ is now $[x]^i\otimes y^ka_i$. Via the identifications: $$K[x]/(p_1)\otimes_kK[y]\cong K[x]\otimes _k[y]/(p_1\otimes 1)\cong K[x,y]/(p_1)$$,
we conclude that the the morphism $K[x,y]\rightarrow K(\theta_1)[y]$ given by mapping $x\mapsto \theta_1$ and $y\mapsto y$ has kernel $(p_1)$, where this ideal is now generated over all of $K[x,y]$.
Now first suppose that $\theta_2\in K(\theta_1)$, then $\theta_2=b_i\theta^i_1$, and we have that the $K(\theta_1)[y]/(y-\theta_2)\cong K(\theta_1,\theta_2)$. Under our chain of isomorphisms we see:
\begin{align}
(y-\theta_2)\mapsto (1\otimes y- \theta_1^i\otimes b_i)\mapsto([1]\otimes y-[x^i]\otimes a_i)\mapsto ([1\otimes y]-[x^i\otimes a_i])\mapsto ([y-x^ia_i])
\end{align}
so:
$$K(\theta_1,\theta_2)\cong (K[x,y]/(p_1))/([y-x^ia_i])$$
Now there is a natural bijection between ideals of $R/I$ and and ideals of $R$ containing $I$, given by $J\subset R/I\mapsto\pi^{-1}(J)$. In this case we must have that $\pi^{-1}(([y-x^ia_i])=(y-x^ia_i)+(p_1)$. It follows that the kernel in the case is the above sum of ideals.
If $\theta_2\notin K(\theta_1)$, then $\theta_1$ could in $K(\theta_2)$, and we repeat the same argument. Otherwise, there exists a minimal polynomial $p_2$ in $y$ over $K(\theta_1)$ such that $K(\theta_1)[y]/(p_2)\cong K(\theta_1,\theta_2)$. If $p_2$ can be taken to have coefficients in $K$, then by tracing through the isomorphisms we will get that the kernel of the morphism is $(p_1)+(p_2)$. If this minimal polynomial has coefficients in $K(\theta_1)$, then we can write that $p_2(y)=a_{0i}\theta_1^i+\cdots+a_{ni}\theta_1^iy^n=a_{kj}\theta_1^jy^k$. Under the above isomorphisms, this gets mapped to the polynomial $a_{kj}x^jy^k$, and the kernel is then given by the sum $(a_{kj}x^jy^k)+(p_1)$.

I don't understand what are the $a_i$'s in the formula just above the sentence "Now there is a natural bijection..." Are they equal to $b_i$?

Oh yea that’s my bad those $a_i$’s are supposed to be $b_i$
